# C++ How do I fix this

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
void getScore(int& score, ifstream& inFile);
void calcAverage(int testScr1, int testScr2, int testScr3, int testScr4, int testcr5);
int findLowest(int testScr1, int testScr2, int testScr3, int testScr4, int testScr5);
int grades(int testScr1, int testScr2, int testScr3, int testScr4, int testScr5);
int main()
{
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("grades.txt");
int lowest = 100;
int testScr1, testScr2, testScr3, testScr4, testScr5;


getScore(testScr1, inFile);
if (testScr1 < lowest)
{
    lowest = testScr1;
}
getScore(testScr2, inFile);
if (testScr2 < lowest)
{
    lowest = testScr2;
}
getScore(testScr3, inFile);
 if (testScr3 < lowest)
{
     lowest = testScr3;
}
getScore(testScr4, inFile);
 if (testScr4 < lowest)
{
    lowest = testScr4;
}
getScore(testScr5, inFile);
 if (testScr5 < lowest)
{
    lowest = testScr5;
}
calcAverage(testScr1, testScr2, testScr3, testScr4, testScr5);

inFile.close();

return lowest;
}

void getScore(int& score, ifstream& inFile)
{
inFile >> score;
}


void calcAverage(int testScr1, int testScr2, int testScr3, int testScr4, int testScr5)
{
int sum = 0;
int lowest;
double average;

lowest = findLowest(testScr1, testScr2, testScr3, testScr4, testScr5);

sum = testScr1 + testScr2 + testScr3 + testScr4 + testScr5 - lowest;
average = sum / 4.0;

cout << setw(4) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
cout << "The avergae of the four highest scores are: " << average << endl;
}

int findLowest(int testScr1, int testScr2, int testScr3, int testScr4, int testScr5)
{
int lowest = testScr1;

cout << "The lowest test score is: " << lowest << endl;

return lowest;
}
```

Here is my problem..This program reads a txt file with 5 grades in it. Its suppose to return back the lowest grade and then report back the average of the 4 remaining grades which it appears to do. The problem I have is that at the bottom I am pretty sure that I am telling the program to read back testScr1 as always being the lowest. This is not my desire and I am pretty sure this is the last problem. I don't know how to resolve this problem. I am new to programming which is why the code probably does not look the best in the world and the solution is probably easy but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Please format your code on here so we can read it.

Comment: Use a debugger, it will tell you EXACTLY what is happening

Comment: you are finding the lowest in your main(), I don't know why you wrote another, erroneous, findLowest function. You noted the problem yourself, it's transitively just outputting test score 1.

Answer (score 3):

You really should take a crack at using the debugger to step through your code, which would help you validate your suspicion.

However, your instinct was correct. You're always assigning `testScr1` to `lowest`. You already calculated the value of `lowest` as you read the 5 grades, so can either ditch that part and fix `findLowest()` or ditch `findLowest()`.

Comment: I have to use void getScore() to read a file and store it in reference parameter variable. This function should be called by main once for each of the 5 scores. I have to use void calcAverage() to calculate and display the average of the 4 highest scores. This function should be called on just once by main, and should be passed the five scores.  And finally I have to use int findLowest() which should find and return the lowest of the five scores passed to it. It should be called by calAverage, which uses the function to determine which of the five scores to drop.